# Ultra fast big database request

Tags: database, indexing

I want to take data from a list of about 7 millions records, so I don't know how to manage this.

And I need to do it incredible fast ... it's a simple 7 million records (text, no longer than 100 bytes each).

MySQL is too slow although is indexed, anything really really fast ?

Comment: Show some code to see what you've tried so far as well as the benchmarking results which led you to the conclusion that MySQL isn't fast enough.

Comment: Eventually did you do it really really fast?